# Xen reports that "Host does not support virtualization type 'hvm'"

Tags: linux, centos, xen

```
[root@www www]# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5500  @ 2.80GHz
stepping    : 10
cpu MHz     : 2800.428
cache size  : 2048 KB
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu tsc msr pae cx8 apic mtrr cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss nx constant_tsc up pni ssse3
bogomips    : 7046.54
```

I want create a virtual machine
I used the command
`[root@www www]# virt-install -n vm01 -r 512 -f /vm/vm01.img -l (this my domainname) -network=network:default -s 10 -nographics -vcpus=2`

but the command reported an error

```
-----ERROR    Host does not support virtualization type 'hvm'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Xen needs VT extensions for hardware VMs (as opposed to paravirtualised VMs) to be enabled to work. Your error message, and the cpu flags indicate that VT is enabled or present in the system. The cpu flag for it is vmx, and [intel's datasheet says that the processor has it](http://ark.intel.com/products/42800/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E5500-2M-Cache-2_80-GHz-800-MHz-FSB).

Ideally *all* you need to do is to go into bios and enable Virtualization Extensions . *Some* manufacturers may do a silly thing and disable VT altogether, so your milage in doing this may vary.